# Handling errors with Genie

Tags: genie

I am trying to refactor a [python class](https://github.com/dmulholland/clio) into Genie, but I am stuck with how to handle errors. Some pointers would be greatly appreciated.

If I understood properly, the way of handling errors with Genie is using Try...except blocks, but how to translate the following type of error handling into this paradigm:

```
# Enable dictionary/list-style access to options and arguments.
def __getitem__(self, key):
    if isinstance(key, int):
        if key < len(self.arguments):
            return self.arguments[key]
        else:
            raise ArgParserError(
                "positional argument index [%s] is out of bounds" % key
            )
    else:
        option = self._get_opt(key)
        return option.value
```

The code I am at right now looks like (in Genie):

```
def getitem (key:int):string
    if key.is_int()
        if key < len(_arguments)
            return _arguments[key]
        else
            raise ArgParserError(
                "positional argument index [%s] is out of bounds", key
            )
    else
        var option = _get_opt(key)
        return option.value
```

This is a dummy code, I am only modelling the problem and I am aware that it will not compile as is. I am only looking for a pointer on how to transate the '''raise''' command from python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the error type as an `exception` and then identify that your `getitem` function `raises` such an error:

```
exception ArgParserError
    OUT_OF_BOUNDS

def getitem( key:int ):string raises ArgParserError
    if key < len(_arguments)
        return _arguments[key]
    else
        raise new ArgParserError.OUT_OF_BOUNDS(
            "positional argument index [%s] is out of bounds", key
             )
```

Genie is statically typed so the `if key.is_int()` is unnecessary. The Vala compiler will check at compile time that all calls to the `getitem` function pass an integer as the argument.

An alternative approach is to use an `out` parameter for the result value and use the function's return value to signal if the result is valid:

```
def getitem( key:uint, out value:string ):bool
    result:bool = false
    value = ""
    if key < _arguments.length
        value = _arguments[ key ]
        result = true
    else
        info( "positional argument index [%s] is out of bounds", key )
    return result
```

By making the key an unsigned integer, `uint`, a negative index can't be passed. The call to `info()` will log some details of the out of bounds index should you need it for debugging later.

Comment: Is OUT_OF_BOUNDS a type definition that I can come up with, or there a list of options that I can use?

Comment: The example uses one I made up, you can change it to whatever you like. There are existing library definitions for exceptions if you want to use those instead, for example GLib.IOError